golang concurrency deadlock issue
In one part of my flow, I created a buffered channel. Inside the doWork function, there are cases where it needs to execute itself again. However, the code below results in an "all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!" error, and I'm struggling to understand why this happens.
How can I correctly implement the concurrency here, and what is causing the deadlock issue?
Thanks in advance!
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "log/slog"
    "runtime/debug"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    signal := make(chan bool, 2)

    go func() {
        slog.Default().Info("worker started")

        for s := range signal {
            if s {
                doWork(signal)
            }
        }
        slog.Default().Info("worker stopped")

    }()
    for {
        scan(signal)
    }
}

func doWork(signal chan bool) {
    fmt.Println("work started")
    signal <- true
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("work finished")
}


the code for your scan function is missing. Can you please add it to your question ?

Channel Blocking in doWork: When doWork runs, it tries to send a true value to the signal channel with signal <- true. This blocks if there is no available space in the channel buffer. This will cause the gorouting to block and cause the deadlock.

Think of the doWork function like a machine that keeps putting items into a box (signal channel) every time it runs. The worker who takes items out of the box only does so one item at a time, and only after each round of putting items in. Eventually, the box gets full because the worker can't empty it fast enough, causing everything to stop (in above case deadlock) because there's nowhere to put the new items.
Remove signal <- true in doWork: This prevents doWork from adding unnecessary signals back into the channel.
Your scan function is missing from the provided code. Additionally, I suggest reducing the channel size to 1. This way, the scan function will only send the next signal when the worker is ready to process it.
